# URL is opening very small tab in Chromium browser [ Node JS with Puppeteer]

Tags: puppeteer

I'm facing issue in chromium browser with one URL by using Node JS code.

[image]

[image]

Node JS with Puppeteer

Comment: Please share a [mcve] and provide OS, package.json and screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the viewport size with [`page.setViewport`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setviewport/).

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1080, // change these numbers
  height: 720, // change these numbers
  deviceScaleFactor: 1,
});
await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

Comment: Hi Carter, Thanks for your support.
my problem is still not resolved, if you observe the above screenshots. After web url opened i'm unable to see the elements values 
ex : if right click on Domain\Username filed in to check the inspect element, i'm unable to see the back end  input value, instead of this i can see whole URL inspect values.

Comment: Hi @veerababubandi I see. This question is about the size of the puppeteer window if I am correct. If you have another question, I would ask I new question on this site.

Comment: Hi Carter, Issue is not about size. Issue is, showing full element values of the URL. not able to see specific input element value

Comment: okay, you'll need to provide specific details of the problem (please add them to the question, not a comment here)